# Please tell me how can I make label1 background transparent?

Tags: c#

Please tell me how can I make label1 background transparent?

This does not work.

```
label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: thanks, but that not this information

Comment: I think that this is precisely what you need. But please note:  "Windows Forms controls do not support true transparency. The background of a transparent Windows Forms control is painted by its parent."

Comment: _This does not work._ Yes it does. But you need to make sure it is __nested__ in __one__ other control; this must be done __in code__ for __some__ controls like PictureBox: `label.Parent = picturebox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the [`BackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) property should be correct, however you'll also need to ensure that the specific control you are using has support enabled for a transparent background as mentioned in the documentation :

> The BackColor property does not support transparent colors unless the  `SupportsTransparentBackColor` value of System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles is set to true.

By default a Label will pull the background color of it's container, so if it was simply on a Form directly, you should be able to use :

```
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        // Indicate this form would explicitly support transparency
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        // Make your label transparent
        label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to make sure that it's container element supports transparency and is transparent.

Comment: That's it! Precisely what i meant.